# Проблема с приложением, работающим с шифром виженера

Tags: java, android, криптография

Здравствуйте. Так получилось, что мне необходимо написать приложение, работающее с шифром Виженера (шифровка/дешифровка). Кто не в курсе, каким образом шифр работает, можете воспользоваться гуглом. Так, теперь к сути:
Есть участок кода

```
char[] alphabet = {'а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',
        'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я'};
public int findInArr(char whatToFind, char[] where) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= where.length; i++) {
        if (where[i] == whatToFind) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;//Эта строка добавлена, дабы компилятор не ругался на отсутствие "return"
}
public String encrypt_N(String text, String key) {
    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if(text.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            int num = findInArr(text.charAt(i), alphabet);
            int num2 = findInArr(key.charAt(i % key.length()), alphabet);
            answer.append(alphabet[((num + num2) % 33)]);
        }
        else {
            answer.append(' ');
        }
    }
    return answer.toString();
}
public String decrypt_N(String text, String key) {
    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if(text.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            int num = findInArr(text.charAt(i), alphabet);
            int num2 = findInArr(key.charAt(i), alphabet);
            if((num - num2) < 0) {
                answer.append(alphabet[-(num - num2) % 33]);
            }
            else if ((num - num2) >= 0) {
                answer.append(alphabet[(num - num2) % 33]);
            }
        }
        else {
            answer.append(' ');
        }
    }
    return answer.toString();
}
```

Функция encrypt_N работает идеально, так как нужно. А вот при вызове функции decrypt_N приложение вылетает. Почему, для меня остается загадкой. Компилятор, при этом, ни на что не ругается. Одна важная(наверное) деталь: при попытке , например, зашифровать символ "в" с ключом "а", все работает нормально, но если шифровать "вв", то опять-таки приложение вылетит.

Comment: Стектрейс ошибки при падении приложите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас батенька, переменные `text` и `key` имеют разные длины, а вы пишете:

```
int num = findInArr(text.charAt(i), alphabet);
int num2 = findInArr(key.charAt(i), alphabet);
```

где `i` пробегает от `0` до `text.length()` - поэтому и будет падать с `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` (если `key.length() < text.length()`)

**P.S.** научитесь следить за логами и включите отладчик.